# Can we modify timestamp in time picker in grafana?

Tags: grafana, druid

I am using Druid as datasource for my grafana.
I want to ignore the first and last data points from the druid query result(like trimming the edges).
I am thinking of modifying  the timestamp passed to druid query from the timepicker. But I cannot find a way to modify the timestamp choosen from the timepicker in grafana. Is there any other way to ignore the first and last data points?
Sample query sent by grafana

```
"__time" >= TIME_PARSE('2022-02-13T07:32:46.055Z') AND "__time" <= TIME_PARSE('2022-02-13T10:32:46.055Z')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Druid specifically, but I can answer your question and tell you that it is possible to modify the time range selected by the time picker.

That is by using the [built in variables $__from and $__to](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/global-variables/#__from-and-__to). Those give you begin and respectively end of the selected time range in UNIX milliseconds. You can then add/subtract milliseconds to/from those to modify the time range used in your query (e.g. in the WHERE clause).

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can use `OFFSET 1` to skip the first row of the result, so this should allow you to remove the first data point. Unfortunately, that only solved half of your question.

You can use `LIMIT N` so that only N rows are returned. In principle, if you know how many rows are in the result, you could use `OFFSET 1 LIMIT <rowcount> - 2` to achieve what you want as long as rowcount > 2. But unless you have a fixed set of values per timeframe, it will likely prove hard to get that .

https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html#limit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any sql data source and want to pass value chosen from the date picker panel then inbuilt time series variable can be used

```
WHERE CAST(date_of_birth as date) between  $__timeFrom() and $__timeTo()
```

And whatever you choose on top of  the date picker ,picked values will be replaced here more info here https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/